Unplanned interim analysis
Are there any sources that nicely summarize why unplanned interim analysis is not an optimal practice? I work with several biologists who routinely do unplanned interim analysis and report these as if they were "results". Then the continue the study, measure again, report another interim analysis, repeating until they have the final. I've been able to convince most of them that merely plopping down sequential individual charts, accompanied by hand-waving, is less ideal than doing a repeat measure analysis. However, they still want to do interim analyses on what is supposed to be a repeat measures study. Is there a not-too-technical reference that explains why this behavior, although emotionally satisfying, is analytically suboptimal?

Would the reasoning in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22059/adjusting-the-p-value-for-adaptive-sequential-analysis-for-chi-square-test help them at all? Not a direct answer to your question of course.

An optimal practice in terms of what? Without knowing what you're trying to optimize there's no definite answer.

I am sure you are familiar with the expression "no harm, no foul". If the experimenter takes an interim peak at the data, and even runs some analysis of it, and tells their colleagues/supervisor/sponsor about it, but does not stop the study (because an effect has been found), does not change its protocol, does not modify the planned sample size(s), etc., then no harm has been done, and no foul should be called. I assume here that when you say "report", it does not cover publishing. This serves to satisfy the experimenter's curiosity (which we all know can kill a cat, but not a biologist), to brag internally, and, more validly, to reassure all directly interested parties that nothing horribly wrong is going on with the study. All this is fine, and actually should be encouraged. If no action is taken after this interim analysis which alters the planned study (other than possibly pause the study to investigate issues which have nothing to do with statistical analysis), there can be no issue with this interim analysis.

Here is a not too technical reference Common pitfalls in statistical analysis: The perils of multiple testing
I find the same problems in multiple business and scientific settings.  My advice is the following, which you likely already know:

Get buy-in from the biologists at the power analysis stage for how long they will have to wait to get the statistically significant result for your testing method (like a repeated measures study).
Reporting facts during the experiment is fine.  It sometimes helps to show them that an experiment isn't completely failing (for non-statistical reasons).
Continue to reinforce that interim facts are not statistical results or conclusions.
Definitely try to stop anyone from reporting any "interim significance" unless you have picked the appropriate testing procedure like a Sequential Probability Ratio Test.

